# Efficient way to transpose the bit of an integer in python?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Consider a 6 bits integer

```
x = a b c d e f
```

that should be transpose to three integers of 2 bits as follows

```
x1 = a d  
x2 = b e
x3 = c f
```

What is an efficient way to do this in python?

I currently goes as follows

```
bit_list = list( bin(x)[2:] ) # to chop of '0b'

# pad beginning if necessary, to make sure bit_list contains 6 bits
nb_of_bit_to_pad_on_the_left = 6 - len(bit_list)

for i in xrange(nb_of_bit_to_pad_on_the_left):
    bit_list.insert(0,'0')

# transposition
transpose = [ [], [], [] ]
for bit in xrange(0,  6, 2):
    for dimension in xrange(3):
        x = bit_list[bit + dimension]
        transpose[dimension].append(x)

for i in xrange(n):
    bit_in_string = ''.join(transpose[i])
    transpose[i] = int(bit_in_string, 2)
```

but this is slow when transposing a 5*1e6 bits integer, to  one million of 5 bits integer.

Is there a better method?
Or some bitshit magic `<</>>` that will be speedier?

This question arised by trying to make a python implementation of [Skilling Hilbert curve algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10384110/1030312)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
mask = 0b100100

for i in range(2, -1, -1):
    tmp = x & mask
    print(((tmp >> 3 + i) << 1) + ((tmp & (1 << i)) >> i))
    mask >>= 1
```

The first mask extracts only `a` and `d`, then it is shifted to extract only `b` and `e` and then `c` and `f`.

In the `print` statement the numbers are either `x00y00` or `0x00y0` or `00x00y`. The `(tmp >> 3 + i)` transforms these numbers into `x` and then the `<< 1` obtains `x0`.
The `((tmp & (1 << i)) >> i))` first transforms those numbers into `y00`/`y0` or `y` and then right-shifts to obtain simply `y`. Summing the two parts you get the `xy` number you want.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Can you indicate how to efficiently generates the mask for other partitioning, like a 15 bits to three 5 bits. I only can do it with `mask=[]; mask.append ... ; int(mask,2)`.

Comment: Ah, it's ok, for 15 to 5, I can do: `mask = 2**14 + 2**(14-5)`. Thanks

Comment: I forgot one term: `mask = 2**14 + 2**(14-5) + 2**(14-2*5)`

Answer (score 1):

Slices will work if your working with strings ( `bin(x)` ).

```
>>> 
>>> HInt = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO'
>>> x = []
>>> for i in [0, 1, 2]:
    x.append(HInt[i::3])


>>> x[0]
'ADGJM'
>>> x[1]
'BEHKN'
>>> x[2]
'CFILO'
>>>
```