# Efficient way to untranspose the bit of an integer array?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Consider 3 integers of 2 bits, stored in an array

```
x1 = [ 
    ad,
    be,
    cf,
]
```

The integers are shown above with their bits, but they are stored as regular `int`.
The array `x1` is the transpose of the integer `x = abcdef`.

How to untranspose `x1` to get

```
x2 = [ 
    ab,
    cd,
    ef,
]
```

The array `x2` is simply `x` in natural order.

What is an efficient way to do this in python?

My ultimate goal is to do comparison between integers.
So given integers `a` and `b` stored like `x1`, I want to know if `a > b`, by looking at `a1` and `b1`.
Any way to achieve this goal, is a good answer as well.

I can use a string representation of integers, but I would like to use some bit shift magic.

This question is a converse to [Efficient way to transpose the bit of an integer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19479846)

Comment: Your question isn't clear -- do you have a Python lists of length 3, which consists of 3 Python lists of length 2, and you want to shuffle those elements as shown, or do you have three integers in the range 0 to 3, which you are thinking of as corresponding to a matrix, and you want to get another collection of 3 (or is it 1?) integer from that. Please clarify the form of the input and the form of the desired output.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like an interesting problem, but I don't want to spend much time thinking about it before I know better what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
def untranspose(arr):
    x,y,z = arr
    a,d = divmod(x,2)
    b,e = divmod(y,2)
    c,f = divmod(z,2)
    return f + 2*e + 4*d + 8*c + 16*b + 32*a
```

For example,

```
>>> untranspose([1,3,2])
30
```

`[1,3,2]` corresponds to

```
01
11
10
```

so you want the integer 011110:

```
>>> int('011110',2)
30
```