# Way to mapping N dimensional vector to a point

Tags: algorithm, math, mapping, dimensional-modeling, dimension-reduction

I'm facing a problem with mapping, I need mapping N dimensional vectors to one group/point, like [0,1....N-1] to 1 | [1,2....N-1] to 2.

The problem is that, right now I have one function where receive a dimensional vector and the return a point, that point is the result, I want avoid call the function, I already have all results stored in a table, the problem is, I'll remove the function  and now I need mapping the new entry to a existing point.

There is some way to mapping the entry to a correct point?

There is some algorithm to mapping to the correct point?

Some help or advice?

I already saw this topic, but I'm not sure whether Hilbert Curve is the solution, I need study more about it.
[Mapping N-dimensional value to a point on Hilbert curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499166/mapping-n-dimensional-value-to-a-point-on-hilbert-curve)

I'll be grateful.

Comment: You're going to have to show some code, describe in more detail what you want it to do and how it's not meeting your expectations.

Comment: @andand,  actually I want implement 'function reuse', instead of call the function I want reuse some data already stored in a table, this table have the approximate results of my function call, and I want reuse this value, the problem is, how can I mapping a new entry to a result in my table, is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping an n dimensional data to a one dimensional data is called projection. There are lots of ways to project an n dimensional data to a lower dimension the most well-known ones are PCA, SVD, or using radial basis functions. If you do not have your method of projection anymore, you probably can't project another point unless you have a hash-table of the previous projected points. If you happen to have exactly the same point, then you can map it to the same point. However, pay attention that the projection is not one-to-one meaning that there may exist two points that are mapped to the same point in the lower dimension. An example of such a case is the projection of 3D points on the screen on which many points may get mapped to exactly the same points on the screen. As a result, inverse projecting the points usually have ambiguities. About the link that you sent about Hilbert curve, this is a general approach to project a point in ND to a point on a space filling curve (SFC) such as Hilbert, Peano, etc. This website at MIT has interesting stuff about dimension reduction using SFC:
http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/Geometry/MDSFC

Comment: thanks for your help, I'll take a look about your suggestions. @Good Luck